# Python 3 Having an error saving a file, opening it by a different program and comparing list values

Tags: python-3.x

I am ultimately trying to save variables that my browser finds to a file in order for it to be later recalled in order to compare if it has went through those values before. Before I reach that step, I am testing my code and have been running into issues:

First part of my code with no error:

```
import shelve
shelfFile = shelve.open('mydata')
cats = ['Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Simon']
shelfFile['cats'] = cats
shelfFile.close()
```

This does what it is intended to do, saves cats to a file.

```
import shelve
shelfFile = shelve.open('mydata')
cats = shelfFile['cats'] 
shelfFile.close()

new = 'Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Simon'
if new in cats:
    print('Found it!')
else:
    print("There is an error")
```

When I run the code it tells me there is an error rather than saying that it found it. Since the list variables are the same, why are they not matching?

Comment: Can you post the error or the stack trace you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen a declaration of variables through the "comma-separated list" as you did: `new = 'Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Simon'`.

I'm pretty sure you just did typo and should use an array for names:

```
new = ['Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Simon']
for item in new:
    if item in cats:
        print('Found it!')
else:
    print("Not found")
```

or:

```
new = ['Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Simon']
for item in new:
    if item in cats:
        print(f'Found {item}!')
else:
    print(f'{item} is not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  checking a tuple available in a list

`new = 'Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Simon'` is a [tuple](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/) object 
and you are expecting a `cats = ['Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Simon']` as a list.

If `cats = shelfFile['cats']` returns the list of 
cats then you need to do is

```
for n in new:
    if n in cats:
        print('Found it!')
    else:
        print('Not found')
```

You can demonstrate the logic by running this script

```
>>> x = "a", "b", "c"
>>> print(x)
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> y = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> x in y
False
>>> for n in x:
...     if n in y:
...         print("found")
found
found
found
```